# How can aop reduce code tangling in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and learning Spring aop. Two advantages of AOP are :

1. Eliminate code scattering
2. To avoid code tangling

The first  one makes sense to me because  of duplication of same code being used in many classes and by using an aspect we can avoid duplicating OF the code in many classes instead define a point cut that will determine where the code will be implemented.

However how do we avoid code tangling in spring?I am not able to find a simple example to show how aop avoid code tangling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"code tangling" means that one code fragment is responsible for more than one requirement.

AOP helps separating them.

For example you have the two requirements:
 - Delete a User
 - Every action that is done to an user needs to be logged

Now you can use AOP to separate the logging stuff out to an aspect and you will got two single code fragments (the delete function and the logging aspect) that are now responsible only for one requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Code tangling**: Modules in a software system may **simultaneously interact with several requirements**
For example, oftentimes developers simultaneously think about business logic, performance, synchronization, logging, and security. Such a multitude of requirements results in the simultaneous presence of elements from each concern's implementation, resulting in code tangling.